# How to disable / change the photoshop cc splash screen (on Mac)

Tags: applications, adobe-photoshop

When you open photoshop cc on mac you get this image: [Photoshop CC Splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J8oH.jpg)

I want to disable it, or (if impossible) to change it to my own image.

I know that is not something you can do by just change some pereference but i'm sure there is some kind of a hack that will do it...

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2043396 This maybe?

Or

Search the Photoshop Libraries for Image files. Most likely the image file can be replaced with a different file?

Comment: answers with just links are discouraged, at least summarize the answer. And actually that does not actually talk about the splash screen, just the welcome screen which can be turned off easily. Follow a google link on **that** forum and it says that no you can't change it as it is not a bitmap in the package file, rather compiled into the program.